# Permissions error in Jenkins when building CocoaPods based Xcode workspace

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, cocoapods

I'm trying to setup Jenkins to compile an iOS Xcode project. The xcode project uses CocoaPods. However, I get this error in Jenkins when I attempt a build. All files in the Pods/ directory have full write/read/execute permissions. Any thoughts?

```
/bin/sh -c /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dripdwqnufuksvhcfgcgxajaahyq/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/Script-EAAE77068BA044C9B06632CE.sh 

/Users/samy/Work/mobile/iphone/MyApp/Pods/Pods-resources.sh: line 5:     /Users/samy/Work/mobile/iphone/MyApp/Pods/resources-to-copy-MyApp.txt: Permission denied

** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:

PhaseScriptExecution Copy\ Pods\ Resources /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dripdwqnufuksvhcfgcgxajaahyq/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/Script-EAAE77068BA044C9B06632CE.sh

(1 failure)
Build step 'Xcode' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only workaround I came across was to move the entire Xcode project to `jenkins` user directory.

Answer (score 1):

"Full read/write/execute permissions" for whom? Which user? Jenkins usually runs under it's own user, called `jenkins`

Comment: I have created the user named jenkins as admin and still the same problem. @Slav

Comment: Does this file exist on the jenkins machine? `/Users/samy/Work/mobile/iphone/MyApp/Pods/resources-to-copy-MyApp.txt`

Comment: The file does exist and `jenkins` user has all the rwx permissions to that file

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add a custom build setting `PODS_ROOT`

```
PODS_ROOT=$(PROJECT_DIR)/Pods
```